# Reopening portal question

Tags: support, specific-question

I've added detail to this question:

[In 'portal', pushing interconnected portals on thin portal sized rectangles of material through each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/in-portal-pushing-interconnected-portals-on-thin-portal-sized-rectangles-of-m)

And requested moderator attention for re-opening, but the question is still on-hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I held off on opening it by moderator fiat as it was still borderline in my opinion and I was waiting to see the consensus. I haven't discussed it with the other moderators but I imagine their thought process was the same.

I checked the flag earlier today and it had 4 open votes so I re-opened it.

In general the community here is good at processing both open and close votes so for things like that which do not need moderator intervention we prefer to let the process work without interference. As moderators we're here to step in and help with exceptional situations, whereas in this case the standard closing and opening process was entirely capable of handling things.

This is especially important during the beta phase of the site as we determine together just what is and is not on topic for the site. Moderators could easily overwhelm otherwise valuable input and discussion by the overriding power of our open/close votes. By waiting for it to have 4 open votes already my fifth vote had the same impact as anyone else's.

Comment: Thanks for the vote. And the helpful insight into the process.

Answer (score 1):

We had a short discussion in the chat and most, like me, felt like the question was borderline as Tim B just mentioned. I'm not a mod but I got some moderation privileges. I was not sure what to do with the question so I let the others decide. That's why it took some time. But it's open now and I pretty sure it will stay open.

Comment: I was of the same mind.  Even with the edit I was not sure of the question's intent so I deferred to other users.