# Votes remaining for deleting a question is (probably) wrong

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

In [this answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2494/3202) Michael Kjörling told us that a question that is not well received requires three votes to be deleted. That answer was to [a question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2493/3202) about why the question the OP voted to delete was immediately deleted.

I believe the vote count remaining for deleting questions is not being reported correctly.

I tested by voting to delete the two lowest ranked questions on the site. They are both closed and one has a delete vote already while the other does not.

**[Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/18065/3202) with one delete vote already:**
[image]

**[Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/511/3202) with zero delete votes already:**
[image]

Both questions show that 25 votes are remaining. I would presume that the "25 remaining" is how many more close votes are required before the question is deleted. In these cases, I don't see how that can be the correct value.

Does anyone else get the correct count on either of these questions?

I'm running Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.157 m) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Are you sure the indicated count isn't how many more delete votes you can make for a given time period?

Comment: The 25 votes are remaining is how many more YOU have for this 24 hour period.  How many you have is based on your reputation.

Comment: @bowlturner Yep, Vincent covered that in the answer below :)

Comment: Ya, I read that AFTER I made my comment...  Need to pay more attention...

Comment: Hm. I see what you mean. I think Vincent is correct, but I also think that this is definitely a place that could use a little bit of clarification!

Comment: And I missed this the first time around (but it doesn't really change much). You write here in the introductory sentence about "close votes", but the question was about *delete* votes. Closing a question always takes five votes, unless a diamond moderator steps in and closes the question.

Comment: @Michael Ah, a mistake. We talk about closing far more than deleting. It just slipped in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the 25 vote remaining are the number of deletion votes you can cast:

> [How many times can I vote to delete per day?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)
>
> At 2,000 reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An
>   additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30
>   delete votes per day.

Edited: I quoted the wrong site. We are still in beta and the reputation required is lower : 2000 instead of 10 000.

Comment: The [Worldbuilding SE page](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) would probably be a better link.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. That makes sense. Except a situation where I need to cast that many delete votes.

Comment: However, the wording is confusing so it would still be worth stack exchange changing it - for example if it said "You have 25 votes remaining"